# Copy an existing row "n" number of times in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have a table with a row, can I insert into the same table "x" number of times making a copy of everything in the row except a few columns. Something along the lines:

```
INSERT INTO #tbl
(City, Region, Country)
SELECT 
"Different city", Same region, Same country 5 times.
```

I am trying to do this without using a loop.

Comment: This is bad database design. You should normalize your database to avoid code duplication. Put all the stuff that is identical for the 5 countries into a new row in a new table, and refer to this row in your original table.

Comment: This is for a temp table, not a regular table used in a maintainance script. This is only used for intermediate processing of data.

Comment: Where are your "Different city" values coming from? The only way to do this 5 times w/o a loop is via a join of some sort.

Comment: Let's assume it comes from the `#cities` table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the cities in a separate table, you should be able to do the following:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (City varchar(20), Region varchar(20), Country varchar(20))
INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES('Malmo', 'Skane', 'Sweden')

--Borrowing some code from @aF.
DECLARE @cities TABLE (city varchar(20))

INSERT INTO @cities values ('London')
INSERT INTO @cities values ('Lisbon')
INSERT INTO @cities values ('Paris')
INSERT INTO @cities values ('New York')
INSERT INTO @cities values ('Barcelona')

INSERT INTO @tbl
SELECT cities.city, tbl.Region, tbl.Country
FROM (select top 1 Region, Country from @tbl) tbl, @cities cities
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the cities in another table you can do it like this:

```
create table #cities (
  city varchar(30)
)

INSERT INTO #cities values ('London')
INSERT INTO #cities values ('Lisbon')
INSERT INTO #cities values ('Paris')
INSERT INTO #cities values ('New York')
INSERT INTO #cities values ('Barcelona')

INSERT INTO #tbl
(City, Region, Country)
SELECT c.city, 'REGION', 'COUNTRY' from #cities c

drop table #cities
```

Comment: The `region` and `country` exists in the `#tbl`. How do I select that row in the `INSERT`?

Comment: do you want to insert the same five cities to each region/country that existe is #tbl? Or to one specific region/country?